# How does coconut milk change the taste of coffee?

Tags: flavored-coffee, coffee-culture

My father bought coconut milk several days ago. So, I've been wondering: how does coconut milk change the taste of coffee?

Is there a coffee variant which would taste awesome with it?

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried that (trying to make [Bulletproof Coffee](https://www.bulletproofexec.com/how-to-make-your-coffee-bulletproof-and-your-morning-too/)) with homemade coconut-milk and it's awesome.

The benefits on focusing are amazing (I'm a programmer & I really feel that) with coffee. I tried that with (normal) butter and another one just with (homemade) almond milk + coconut milk + drip coffee (Chemex)

I'm planning on buying some market coconut-oil, but it's too expensive. I really recommend it to you. Also if you blend it (to mix everything more consistent) it gives you a latte feel.